# SQL date format convert? [dd.mm.yy to YYYY-MM-DD]

Tags: mysql, sql, date, format, sql-function

is there mySQL function to convert a date from format dd.mm.yy to YYYY-MM-DD?

for example, `03.09.13 -> 2013-09-03`.

Comment: Is your input a date type, or is it a string that's literally `03.09.13`?

Comment: @ppeterka66 Yes, and asking here probably means that I didn't find/understood an answer for that.

Comment: @EdGibbs it's a string.

Comment: Convert your string to a date and then back to a string in the new format.

Comment: @user2216190 : simple answer is no. I would imagine if you installed some UDF library for regex, you could do something way over the top with regex matching and concocting a new date string. You'd be better off using your dynamic language to pre-process the date. Are you using PHP?

Comment: @DanBracuk it needs to automatically as possible - we are transfering a part of a database to a new format...

Comment: @Lee yes, PHP. but if it is too complicated to do it is possible to just leave it. What's your solution?

Comment: you could use the substr example posted below. It's not what i'd recommend or even do myself, but its the only thing that will work as an in-query thing

Comment: If you're transferring to a new format, I'd strongly recommend changing the column to a `DATE` type. It will work much better like that, and you'll never have to worry about invalid values.

Comment: @EdGibbs that's what we are doing

Comment: wouldn't you want `2013-09-03` when given `03.09.13` instead of `2013-09-13`

Comment: Looks like Ed Gibbs come to the rescue, didnt realise that function ever existed.

Comment: If your new datatype is going to be date, why are you worried about the format at all?

Comment: Becouse we are changing the whole databases - and some data needs to be transfered as possible.

Comment: @EdGibbs That worked, Greate solution!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Since your input is a string in the form `03.09.13`, I'll assume (since today is September 3, 2013) that it's `dd.mm.yy`. You can convert it to a date using [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
STR_TO_DATE(myVal, '%d.%m.%y')
```

Then you can format it back to a string using [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(myVal, '%d.%m.%y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Note that the year is `%y` (lowercase "y") in `STR_TO_DATE` and `%Y` (uppercase "Y") in `DATE_FORMAT`. The lowercase version is for two-digit years and the uppercase is for four-digit years.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(myVal, '%d.%m.%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') Y is capital letter

Comment: Rajavel - it's a lowercase `y` in the first one because the input string has a 2-digit year (`03.09.13`). In the second one it's uppercase so the output will be a 4-digit year (`2013-09-03`).

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
SELECT CONCAT(
'20',
SUBSTR('03.09.13', 7, 2),
'-',
SUBSTR('03.09.13', 4, 2),
'-',
SUBSTR('03.09.13', 1, 2))
```

Fiddle [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2bad6e/7).

More about formats you can read in the corresponding [manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).
Tip: if this is about conversion value from non-datetime field - better to use DATE/DATETIME data type instead. However, this is a **bad idea** to operate with dates via string functions. Above there is a nice trick with `STR_TO_DATE` (will not repeat that code, updated to fit better)

Comment: Won't work, `DATE_FORMAT` requires the input date to be in Y-m-d format anyway. Your query (if you run it) will return `2003-09-13`, obviously incorrect

Comment: Reverted my vote to an upvote, purely because i didn't think of this way. Not something i'd personally recommend (as im sure you wouldnt either), but given his unique requirements, seems to be the only way of doing it.

Comment: @Lee - yes, I disagree with such method of getting result, yet in tha same time it will fit for OP. I really can't understand why people using string date types for dates.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Thats one of the things that getting fixed :)

Comment: My requirement was to convert  a string dd-mm-yy to dd-mm-yyyy. I modified the above code as below

`SELECT CONCAT(
SUBSTR('03.09.13', 1, 2),
'-',
SUBSTR('03.09.13', 4, 2),
'-',
'20',
SUBSTR('03.09.13', 7, 2))`

Answer (score 1):

Dates are stored using an internal format.  You can use the function `date_format()` to convert it to a string using a variety of formats.  For yours in particular:

```
select date_format(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d')
```