# Show month of a full date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a column in my database with populated with full dates : (0000-00-00)
I need to show this date as a month string (ex. January).

I have too choices on my SQL QUERY here:

1 create a case when month is '01' = 'January' (which I believe is the best option since I could then change the string however I want (In Portuguese, with the first letter capital for example). I was not able to do that, I tried substring, but dates don´t like substring statements.

2 just show that date as month:

```
MONTH(DT_CANCEL)
```

However, I need to show the string (January) and the above only outputs 01

What is the best option (and how) can I show the full month name of a date in a SQL QUERY?

Using MySQL.

Comment: Sorry, MYSQL it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use MonthName:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME('2009-05-18');
```

This will output May.

Reference here: 
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-monthname-function.php

Comment: This worked for me, now, is it possible to show only the three first letters? Jan ? instead of January?

Comment: I just used: LEFT(MONTHNAME(DT_CANCEL), 3) , worked, thanks man!

Comment: @Gauravsa SELECT MONTHNAME('2009-05-05'); In this statement, how to decide month . Format may be "yyyy-mm-dd" or "yyyy-dd-mm"

Comment: u Can use str_to_date function and then use monthname

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597051/sql-date-format-convert-dd-mm-yy-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 1):

In mysql you can use monthname

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(DT_CANCEL) from your_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql:

```
select date_format('2018-12-01','%M'); /* prints December*/

select date_format('2018-12-01','%b'); /* prints Dec*/
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, use TO_CHAR:

```
select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Month') FROM dual;

December
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL Server, you don't need to write a Case statement, try below:

```
SET LANGUAGE Portuguese

SELECT UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(month, getdate()),1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(DATENAME(month, 
getdate()),2,LEN(DATENAME(month, getdate()))))
```

If you want to reset language for your server, you can see the list of aliases by running the script below:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.syslanguages
```