# Convert 2021-1-01 to 2021-01-01 in SQL (YYYY-M-DD TO YYYY-MM-DD)

Tags: mysql, sql

As title.

There is a way to convert a date from YYYY-M-DD to YYYY-MM-DD?

In db I have 2021-1-01 but I need to get 2021-01-01.

TY

**EDIT**

I have a value 2021-1-01 and i need to insert it in a db like date 2021-01-01, maybe before I not was clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL date format convert? \[dd.mm.yy to YYYY-MM-DD\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597051/sql-date-format-convert-dd-mm-yy-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: Are you saying that you have `2021-1-01` in a variable (PHP maybe) and you want to convert it into a date that will work in a MySQL DATE type column?

Comment: **Where** do you have the date? Are you using a programing language?

Comment: This value become from a XML file. In tag I have <date>2021-1-01</date> and I need to import this value in SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `'2021-1-01'`, then you do not have a date.  You have a string.  That is a problem with your data model.  You should fix the data to store dates using appropriate types -- which are not strings.

MySQL is pretty smart about converting dates, so you can just use:

```
select date(string_as_date_col)
```

You can change the type of the column in the table using:

```
alter table t modify column string_as_date_column date
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b524decea515d4efb9dd37b2928f8c32) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: maybe I not explain well. My value is 2021-1-01 and I need to upload it as a date format in a SQL db.